# Multiple files not uploaded to server in php

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery multi file plugin to upload multiple files.The problem I face is not all files are uploaded to server.I am using `jquery.MultiFile.js` .I have put
the following code to allow only 5MB should be the upoad file limit.This is workin fine but all files are not uploading.The post_max_size is 8M.My php version is 5.4

```
<input  type="file" name="file[]" class="multi _new_file_row maxsize-5128" />
```

When I tried to print the `$_FILES['file']` from the loop,I am getting only 5 files.I didnt understand why this happens

Comment: your uploadede file is more than you declared

Comment: Only 5 files are allowed to upload even though total size is less than 5mb @mohsen

Comment: if your 5 file size more than 5mb what will happen? upload failed or missed file

Comment: Based on the question's description it won't be easy to pinpoint the issue. Do you have any Javascript or PHP errors? What about the web server's logs (are there requests for all files, or only for some)? Without some debugging or clear problem, most definitely you won't get an answer.

Comment: @milz It was the problem in php for each loop.I have solved that and now its fine.

Answer (score 0):

change php.ini:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```